# Recent update to Visual Studio 2017 on my SharePoint 2013 server broke Add-in debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sharepoint-2013, provider-hosted

I have a SharePoint 2013 server.
We have Visual studio 2015 and 2017 installed on it.
After a recent VS2017 update (15.8.1), debugging a Provider hosteed Add-in via Visual Studio 2017 is broken.

I receive the generic, “An error has occurred processing your request”. I went through all the necessary steps such as

- client ID
- windows auth enabled
- anonymous auth disabled
- certificate comes back in the TokenHelper.cs

Weird thing is now it inly opens one browser tab and goes directly to localhost.  It does not go to the SharePoint URL with the redirect message.  Of course the code dies because there are no query string parameters such as the SPHostUrl.

Has anyone seen similar issues?

Comment: What type of error you recieved can you add some more details or screenshot?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: This is how it works, when you publish from VS2017 after publish it will open a tab in a browser without Standard Tokens. What your wsp is doing?

Comment: When you run your add-in from visual studio via debug mode it will open a browser to the sharepoint URL with a Redirect link.  You click the redirect link and it sends you to the add-in (localhost address) with standard tokens.